# Is there a .Net Client library for the SophosLabs Intelix API?

Tags: sophoslabs-intelix

I can't seem to locate any nuget packages for it.

I'm feeling a little obtuse, but I am finding myself iterating over every status code for the calls to each endpoint, mapping out the returned objects.

Is there a Visual Studio tool that creates the client interface from the YAML files that consumes the API?

Comment: Hi. Swagger is the metadata for the API. Could you explain a bit more what you are looking for? Preferably with some examples (like in which format would you like to see the metadata).

Comment: @LászlóÁcs - I realized that the actual answer I am seeking is for a different question.  I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, unfortunately at time of writing there isn't a client library for Intelix in .NET.